# react-native-track-player TrackPlayer.play() doesn't throw an error if the audio url doesn't work

Tags: react-native, audio, react-native-track-player

EDIT: I'm using `react-native-track-player": "^3.2.0"`

I have an issue with "react-native-track-player".

The audio files in my app are played via this function:

```
async function setUpNewTrack() {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.reset()
      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: podcastEpisode._id,
        url: podcastEpisode.attributes.audio,
        title: podcastEpisode.attributes.title,
        artist: podcastEpisode.attributes.author,
        artwork: podcastEpisode.attributes.image || podcastEpisode.relationships.podcast.data.image,
        description: podcastEpisode.attributes.description || podcastEpisode.attributes.content,
      })
      setCurrentPlayingPodcast(podcastEpisode)

      if (podcastPlaybackTime !== 0) {
        await TrackPlayer.seekTo(podcastPlaybackTime)
      }
      await TrackPlayer.play()
      setCurrentPlayingPodcastId(podcastEpisode._id)
      setCurrentlyPlayPodcast(podcastEpisode._id)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error playing the podcast")
      console.error({
        message: "Error in PodcastMediaPlayer.tsx: setUpNewTrack",
        error,
      })
    }
  }
```

So when the user press "Play" button, this function is executed. And it works fine unless the `podcastEpisode.attributes.audio` is not valid. Because the links are controlled by third-party, sometimes they get deleted and stop working, and I cannot do anything about it.

My problem with "react-native-track-player" is that the playback state after the executing `TrackPlayer.play()` it is `connecting` and even tho it will never connect, because the link is broken, `TrackPlayer.play()` function doesn't throw an error.

So I'm wondering how to handle this kind of situations, when the audio link doesn't work, is there some way to make `TrackPlayer.play()` to throw an error if it cannot connect for some time, some kind of timeout?

I tried to solve it with creating a timeout if the `TrackPlayer.play()` promise is not resolved, but I guess no matter if the `playBackState` is `playing` or `connecting` the promise from `TrackPlayer.play()` is considered as resolved.

This is my failed attempt to fix the issue:

```
 const playerLoadingTimeout = new Promise(
        (_resolve, reject) =>
          setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("We couldn't load the podcast.")), 10000), // 10 seconds
      )
      await Promise.race([TrackPlayer.play(), playerLoadingTimeout])
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => Alert.alert("OHO !", err.message))
```

I have also tried to follow the `playbackState` and use timer, so if the `playbackState` is `connecting` more than 10 seconds, to restart the player, but it didn't worked.

```
  function handleLongConnection() {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        if (playBackState === State.Connecting || playBackState === State.Buffering) {
          Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error playing the podcast")
          TrackPlayer.reset()
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("THERE IS AN ERROR", error)
      }
    }, 10000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return handleLongConnection()
  }, [playBackState])
```

I have also noticed, that sometimes when I call `TrackPlayer.reset()` the `playbackState` actually change to `State.Pause` instead of `State.None` as it suppose to. This have been a problem on iOS, on Android, when I call `TrackPlayer.reset()` the `playbackState` change to `idle` which is alright, as I can track when the track has stopped.